# how to run two different jquery on page load but one after another?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, vuejs2

```js
 mounted: function() {
       $(function(){
          $(document).ready(function(){
            Tour.run([
              {
                element: $('#interest'),
                content: 'by default tour is on the right'
              },
              {
                element: $('#course'),
                content: 'but it can be on top',
                position: 'right'
              },
              {
                element: $('#trade'),
                content: 'bottom',
                position: 'right'
              },
              {
                element: $('#district'),
                content: 'and finally on the left',
                position: 'right'
              },
              {
                element: $('#InstituteSearch'),
                content: 'and finally on the left',
                position: 'right'
              },
              {
                element: $('#btn-search'),
                content: 'and finally on the left',
                position: 'right'
              },
              {
                element: $('#btn-claear'),
                content: 'and finally on the left',
                position: 'right'
              }
            ]);
          });
      });
     (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
          $.magnificPopup.open({
            items: {
                src: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8E6xsac2MU'
            },
            type: 'iframe'
          }, 0);
        });
      })(jQuery);
    },
```

I have these two jquery plugins. One is for overlay & another one is for popup video. Both are executed on page load.I want to popup video on page load first. After closing the video the overlay's jquery should execute.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the first one as a function that you run on close when the video popup is closed.

```
 $.magnificPopup.open({
            items: {
                src: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8E6xsac2MU'
            },
            type: 'iframe',
            close: function() {
                // Will fire when popup is closed
                TourRun();
                    }
          }, 0);
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
mounted: function() {
      $(function(){
          $(document).ready(function(){

       $.magnificPopup.open({
            items: {
                src: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8E6xsac2MU'
            },
            type: 'iframe',
            close: function() {
                // Will fire when popup is closed

                Tour.run([
              {
                element: $('#interest'),
                content: 'by default tour is on the right'
              },
              {
                element: $('#course'),
                content: 'but it can be on top',
                position: 'right'
              },
              {
                element: $('#trade'),
                content: 'bottom',
                position: 'right'
              },
              {
                element: $('#district'),
                content: 'and finally on the left',
                position: 'right'
              },
              {
                element: $('#InstituteSearch'),
                content: 'and finally on the left',
                position: 'right'
              },
              {
                element: $('#btn-search'),
                content: 'and finally on the left',
                position: 'right'
              },
              {
                element: $('#btn-claear'),
                content: 'and finally on the left',
                position: 'right'
              }
            ]);
          }
          }, 0);
        });
      });
              
    },
```

Hello It shows only video Popup, overlay is not running